# How to point many paths to proxy server in nginx

Tags: url, tomcat, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set nginx location that will handle various paths and proxy them to my webapp.

Here is my conf:

```
    server {

    listen          80;
    server_name     www.example.org;

    #this works fine
    location / { 
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/myApp/;
    }

    #not working
    location ~ ^/(.+)$ { 
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/myApp/$1;
    }
}
```

I would like to access myApp with various paths like: /myApp/ABC, /myApp/DEF, myApp/GEH or /myApp/ZZZ.
Of course these paths are not available in myApp. I want them to point to root of myApp and keep url.
Is that possible to archive with nginx ?

Comment: "Of course these paths are not available in myApp" — they should be. How does you app will know, that you came to `/ABC`?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx locations match in order of definition. `location /` is basically a wildcard location, so it will match everything, and nothing will reach the second location. Reverse the order of the two definitions, and it should work. But actually, now that I look at it more closely, I think both locations are essentially doing the same thing:

```
/whatever/path/ ->>proxies-to->> http://localhost:8081/myApp/whatever/path/
```

Answer (score 1):

A very late reply. this might help someone

```
try proxy_pass /myApp/ /location1 /location2;
```

Each location separated with space.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to do a rewrite followed by a proxy pass, I had the same issue. Check here: [How to make a conditional proxy_pass within NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382360/how-to-make-a-conditional-proxy-pass-within-nginx)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).